# In t-sql how do I create a one to one relationship between the columns of a single table?

Tags: t-sql, constraints, one-to-one

I have a table with columns C1,C2,C3, and C4.  A value can appear multiple times in C1 but for each value of C1 there must be a unique value for the combination of columns C3 and C4.  Similarly a value can appear in multiple rows in C3 and C4, but for any particular combination of values in C3 and C4 there must be a unique value in C1. The primary key is C1+C2+C3+C4.  E.g.:

- C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | Comment
- 11 ! 20 | 31 | 41 | Any time C1=11, must have C3=31 and C4=41 and vice versa
- 11 ! 21 | 31 | 41 | OK because C2 is different
- 11 ! 22 | 32 | 41 | Bad because C1=11 but C3<>31
- 11 ! 22 | 31 | 42 | Bad because C1=11 but C4<>41
- 12 ! 23 | 31 | 41 | Bad because C1<>11 but C3=31 and C4=41
- 13 ! 21 | 31 | 42 | Any time C1=12, must have C3=31 and C4=42 and vice versa
  -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on gbn's suggestion (or making it explicit).  The fact that a particular mapping can appear more than once in the original table (e.g., rows 1 and 2 have the same values for C1, C3, and C4) is what makes things difficult.  Use a second table and a foreign key with the first table so that each mapping appears only once in the second table.  Then, the trick is, in the second table, to have a UNIQUE constraint on C1 and a separate UNIQUE constraint on (C3,C4).  Since each value on each side of the map can only appear once in the second table, you've enforced a 1-1 mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Create some tables that have the allowed combinations and use foreign keys

That is, you would have a table as follows

```
C1, C3, C4
11, 31, 41
12, 31, 42
```

Then add a foreign key on your first table on C1, C3 and C4

Comment: Thanks, gbn. Could you please provide more detail?  All 4 columns come from a source outside my control.  I'm trying to enforce the contractual agreement with the outside source because my code will break if they break the 1-1 contract.  What constraint would I use on the proposed extra table to enforce the 1-1 relationship between C1 and C3+C4?  Wouldn't that constraint work just as well on the original table?

Comment: Using a 2nd table avoids having many check constraints on the first table, or one big check constraint. And  you would use a foreign key